# Issue with Validation Accuracy does not improve while training

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have an issue with Validation Accuracy while training Ultrasound images to classify benign and malign images using Transfer Learning with ResNet50.

I tried to change epoch, learning rate, batch size, add more layers, apply Data Augmentation, but nothing is improved. My folder is set as data --> train or test --> benign or malign (for each train and test folder).

Most parts of the code I found online and try to apply to my goal of training. I am using Tensorflow 2.1 and training with CNN. 
My code is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from keras.layers import Input, Lambda, Dense, Flatten, Dropout, BatchNormalization
from keras.models import Model
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
import tensorflow as tf
# from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
import numpy as np
from glob import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

# re-size all the images to this
IMAGE_SIZE = [224, 224]


data_dir = 'C:\Spring 2020\Machine Learning and Computer Vision\data_resize'
os.listdir(data_dir)
valid_path = data_dir+'\\test\\'
train_path = data_dir+'\\train\\'


# Import the Vgg 16 library as shown below and add preprocessing layer to the front of VGG
# Here we will be using imagenet weights

resnet = ResNet50(input_shape=IMAGE_SIZE + [3], weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

# don't train existing weights
for layer in resnet.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

# useful for getting number of output classes
folders = glob(train_path + '\*')

# our layers - you can add more if you want
x = Flatten()(resnet.output)
#x = Flatten()(base_model.output)
x = Dense(4096, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(2048, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(16, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(8, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(4, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
prediction = Dense(1, activation = 'softmax')(x)



# prediction = Dense(len(folders), activation='sigmoid')(x)

# create a model object
model = Model(inputs=resnet.input, outputs=prediction)

# view the structure of the model
model.summary()

# tell the model what cost and optimization method to use
adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(
    learning_rate=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07, amsgrad=False,
    name='adam' 
)
model.compile(
  loss='binary_crossentropy',
  optimizer=adam,
  metrics=['accuracy']
)

# Use the Image Data Generator to import the images from the dataset
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

# Make sure you provide the same target size as initialied for the image size
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_path,
                                                 target_size = (224, 224),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(valid_path,
                                            target_size = (224, 224),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'binary',
                                            shuffle = False)


# fit the model
# Run the cell. It will take some time to execute
early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',patience=20)
r = model.fit_generator(
  training_set,
  validation_data=test_set,
  epochs=30,
  steps_per_epoch=len(training_set),
  validation_steps=len(test_set),
  callbacks = [early_stop]
)


# plot the loss
plt.plot(r.history['loss'], label='train loss')
plt.plot(r.history['val_loss'], label='val loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
plt.savefig('LossVal_loss')

# plot the accuracy
plt.plot(r.history['accuracy'], label='train acc')
plt.plot(r.history['val_accuracy'], label='val acc')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
plt.savefig('AccVal_acc')

import tensorflow as tf

from keras.models import load_model

model.save('model_vgg16.h5')
```

Here is the result while training:

```
runfile('C:/Spring 2020/Machine Learning and Computer Vision/need_to_try.py', wdir='C:/Spring 2020/Machine Learning and Computer Vision')
Using TensorFlow backend.
C:\Users\binhd\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras_applications\resnet50.py:265: UserWarning: The output shape of `ResNet50(include_top=False)` has been changed since Keras 2.2.0.
  warnings.warn('The output shape of `ResNet50(include_top=False)` '
Model: "model_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________

Total params: 445,822,513
Trainable params: 422,234,793
Non-trainable params: 23,587,720
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Found 2198 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 800 images belonging to 2 classes.
Epoch 1/10
69/69 [==============================] - 22s 325ms/step - loss: 7.6573 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 2/10
69/69 [==============================] - 18s 260ms/step - loss: 7.6604 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 3/10
69/69 [==============================] - 19s 274ms/step - loss: 7.6791 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 4/10
69/69 [==============================] - 19s 275ms/step - loss: 7.6604 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 5/10
69/69 [==============================] - 19s 275ms/step - loss: 7.6791 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
```

Here is the plot: y is the number of epoch and x is the percentage (0.5 is 50%).

[image]

[image]

Due to body limitation, I just posted a few beginning and ending layers in summary below:

---

```
____________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 224, 224, 3)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1_pad (ZeroPadding2D)       (None, 230, 230, 3)  0           input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1 (Conv2D)                  (None, 112, 112, 64) 9472        conv1_pad[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn_conv1 (BatchNormalization)   (None, 112, 112, 64) 256         conv1[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)       (None, 112, 112, 64) 0           bn_conv1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
pool1_pad (ZeroPadding2D)       (None, 114, 114, 64) 0           activation_1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 56, 56, 64)   0           pool1_pad[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2a_branch2a (Conv2D)         (None, 56, 56, 64)   4160        max_pooling2d_1[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
    .........
    ........
    .....

activation_47 (Activation)      (None, 7, 7, 512)    0           bn5c_branch2a[0][0]              
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    res5c_branch2b (Conv2D)         (None, 7, 7, 512)    2359808     activation_47[0][0]              
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    bn5c_branch2b (BatchNormalizati (None, 7, 7, 512)    2048        res5c_branch2b[0][0]             
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    activation_48 (Activation)      (None, 7, 7, 512)    0           bn5c_branch2b[0][0]              
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    res5c_branch2c (Conv2D)         (None, 7, 7, 2048)   1050624     activation_48[0][0]              
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    bn5c_branch2c (BatchNormalizati (None, 7, 7, 2048)   8192        res5c_branch2c[0][0]             
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    add_16 (Add)                    (None, 7, 7, 2048)   0           bn5c_branch2c[0][0]              
                                                                     activation_46[0][0]              
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    activation_49 (Activation)      (None, 7, 7, 2048)   0           add_16[0][0]                     
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    flatten_1 (Flatten)             (None, 100352)       0           activation_49[0][0]              
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 4096)         411045888   flatten_1[0][0]                  
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    dense_2 (Dense)                 (None, 2048)         8390656     dense_1[0][0]                    
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    dense_3 (Dense)                 (None, 1024)         2098176     dense_2[0][0]                    
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    dense_4 (Dense)                 (None, 512)          524800      dense_3[0][0]                    
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    dense_5 (Dense)                 (None, 256)          131328      dense_4[0][0]                    
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    dense_6 (Dense)                 (None, 128)          32896       dense_5[0][0]                    
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    dense_7 (Dense)                 (None, 64)           8256        dense_6[0][0]                    
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    dense_8 (Dense)                 (None, 32)           2080        dense_7[0][0]                    
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    dense_9 (Dense)                 (None, 16)           528         dense_8[0][0]                    
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    dense_10 (Dense)                (None, 8)            136         dense_9[0][0]                    
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    dense_11 (Dense)                (None, 4)            36          dense_10[0][0]                   
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    dropout_1 (Dropout)             (None, 4)            0           dense_11[0][0]                   
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    batch_normalization_1 (BatchNor (None, 4)            16          dropout_1[0][0]                  
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    dense_12 (Dense)                (None, 1)            5           batch_normalization_1[0][0]      
    ==================================================================================================
```

I hope to receive assistance from everyone. Please help! I appreciate your time and concern in reading and responding to my post.

Answer (score 0):

Technically softmax is a generalization of sigmoid for multi-class classification. However, I got similar results as you got when I used softmax activation in the last layer. Please check the code [here](https://github.com/jvishnuvardhan/Stackoverflow_Questions/blob/master/Binary_classification_softmax.ipynb).

In the same code, when I replaced `softmax` with `sigmoid`, I got good results as excpected. Please check the [gist here](https://github.com/jvishnuvardhan/Stackoverflow_Questions/blob/master/Binary_classification_sigmoid.ipynb).

You need to change last layer from

```
prediction = Dense(1, activation = 'softmax')(x)
```

to

```
prediction = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)
```

Other than that everything looks good.

#### If the above is not working, Can you try

replacing last layer from

```
prediction = Dense(1, activation = 'softmax')(x)
```

to

```
prediction = Dense(1)(x)
```

After that change the compile from

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer=adam,metrics=['accuracy'])
```

to

model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])

Comment: Could you expand on the reason?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The issue is still there after changing softmax to sigmoid.

Comment: I edited my answer. If the first solution is not working, can you try second one where you need to provide `from_logits=True` in the compile and change last layer without any activation function.

Comment: You can use my code and update according to your code to get wrong accuracy. Alternatively, if your data is not private, share it with me. I will try to find root-cause.